# Static build ffmpeg 0.8

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Is there anywhere an available static build of ffmpeg with all encoder/decoders libs for Linux (not a source tarball, but a binary) ?

Although this question seems trivial, I spent the last half hour looking for it, without any success.

**EDIT** I'm looking for binary to be run on x86 Suse 10 systems. Notice I can't use local package manager as all update repositories have bene removed by admin (to avoid uncontrolled software update).

Comment: Why not ask your admin to install it for you?

Comment: @new123456 Because I'm currently developping a component that will rely upon ffmpeg and be installed on a bouch of serversd using that config. And it's not acceptable to mass install that soft (from my admin's words).

Comment: I figured as much as a [stingy admin](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=programmer+vs+sysadmin), but it never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [one of these rpm packages](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/ffmpeg) will work for you. Or [possibly one of these](http://pkgs.org/package/ffmpeg). Once you have the package that looks like it'll work, you can try installing it with `rpm -i [package name]` I don't believe your repos will matter for that to work.

Failing that kind of solution, here's a tangent, but it should work, go setup a SuSE box just like that one, download and compile ffmpeg from source, copy over the binaries you built. Provided the correct libraries are around, you'll probably be fine.